# (remove duplicated) reindex multidimensional array php jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
[{
    "sys_id": "2015-07-018",
    "account_id": "2015-07-018",
    "Names": [{
        "fname": "Jackie",
        "mname": "Lee",
        "lname": "Chan",
        "suffix": "Jr",
        "city": "Tokyo",
        "town": "Shinagawa-ku",
        "dstrct": "District 2",
        "street": "Jr",
        "contactnum": "1234"
    }, {
        "fname": "Jackie",
        "mname": "Lee",
        "lname": "Chan",
        "suffix": "Jr",
        "city": "Tokyo",
        "town": "Shinagawa-ku",
        "dstrct": "District 2",
        "street": "Jr",
        "contactnum": "1234"
    }, {
        "fname": "Jackie",
        "mname": "Lee",
        "lname": "Chan",
        "suffix": "Jr",
        "city": "Tokyo",
        "town": "Shinagawa-ku",
        "dstrct": "District 2",
        "street": "Jr",
        "contactnum": "1234"
    }, {
        "fname": "Jackie",
        "mname": "Lee",
        "lname": "Chan",
        "suffix": "Sr",
        "city": "Tokyo",
        "town": "Shinagawa-ku",
        "dstrct": "District 2",
        "street": "Sr",
        "contactnum": "1234"
    }, {
        "fname": "Jackie",
        "mname": "Lee",
        "lname": "Chan",
        "suffix": "Sr",
        "city": "Tokyo",
        "town": "Shinagawa-ku",
        "dstrct": "District 2",
        "street": "Sr",
        "contactnum": "1234"
    }, {
        "fname": "Jackie",
        "mname": "Lee",
        "lname": "Chan",
        "suffix": "Sr",
        "city": "Tokyo",
        "town": "Shinagawa-ku",
        "dstrct": "District 2",
        "street": "Sr",
        "contactnum": "1234"
    }]
}]
```

THis my result from ajax request i want to remove the duplicate from the result either from server side or jquery side in my server side i have tried the most common way of removing duplicated array like

```
$input = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $new_data)));
$new_data1 = array_values($input);
echo json_encode($new_data1, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Where in the `$new_data` is the result of my select query. The `print_r($new_data)` will result in

```
Array(
    [2015 - 07 - 018] => Array(
        [sys_id] => 2015 - 07 - 018[account_id] => 2015 - 07 - 018[Names] => Array(
            [0] => Array(
                [fname] => Jackie[mname] => Lee[lname] => Chan[suffix] => Jr[city] => Tokyo[town] => Shinagawa - ku[dstrct] => District 2[street] => Jr[contactnum] => 1234)[1] => Array(
                [fname] => Jackie[mname] => Lee[lname] => Chan[suffix] => Jr[city] => Tokyo[town] => Shinagawa - ku[dstrct] => District 2[street] => Jr[contactnum] => 1234)[2] => Array(
                [fname] => Jackie[mname] => Lee[lname] => Chan[suffix] => Jr[city] => Tokyo[town] => Shinagawa - ku[dstrct] => District 2[street] => Jr[contactnum] => 1234)[3] => Array(
                [fname] => Jackie[mname] => Lee[lname] => Chan[suffix] => Sr[city] => Tokyo[town] => Shinagawa - ku[dstrct] => District 2[street] => Sr[contactnum] => 1234)[4] => Array(
                [fname] => Jackie[mname] => Lee[lname] => Chan[suffix] => Sr[city] => Tokyo[town] => Shinagawa - ku[dstrct] => District 2[street] => Sr[contactnum] => 1234)[5] => Array(
                [fname] => Jackie[mname] => Lee[lname] => Chan[suffix] => Sr[city] => Tokyo[town] => Shinagawa - ku[dstrct] => District 2[street] => Sr[contactnum] => 1234))))
```

`Update`

I tried `print_r($new_data1);` the result is exactly like the result of `print_r($new_data);`

Looking for a way to remove duplicate I found this

`function super_unique($array) {
    $result = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $array)));
    foreach($result as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $result[$key] = super_unique($value);
        }
    }
    return $result;
}`

The task i want to do now is to reindex the array because the output is

```
Array ( [1] => Array ( [sis_id] => 2015-07-018 [account_id] => 2015-07-018 [Names] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [fname] => Jackie [mname] => Lee [lname] => Chan [suffix] => Jr [city] => Tokyo [town] => Shinagawa-ku [brgy] => District 2 [contactnum] => 1234 ) [3] => Array ( [fname] => Jackie [mname] => Lee [lname] => Chan [suffix] => Sr [city] => Tokyo [town] => Shinagawa-ku [brgy] => District 2 [contactnum] => 1234 ) ) ) )
```

I want the old format for the out put

Answer (score 0):

What if you serialize each object in the array to a string (json would be easiest in my opinion) then use the native functions to remove duplicates, then unserialize back to objects?

Sudo code would look like this:

```
$serialized_array = [];
foreach($new_data as $data) {
    $serialized_array[] = json_encode($data);
}

$new_data = []; //reset new_data
$unique = array_unique($serialized_array);
foreach($serialized_array as $string) {
    $new_data[] = json_decode($string);
}
//new_data should now only contain unique data
```

**The main difference between what you're doing and this is serializing and deserializing *each object individually* instead of the entire array. This is the key.**

Comment: do i need to change anything for the code because when i tried it the ouyput is still `http://pastebin.com/jd0HUW7Z`

Comment: change anything for what code? The code in my answer is only sudo code  using php syntax so it will probably need some tweeks to work.